How to set up cuDNN on WSL2 and poetry?
I got a new machine with an Nvidia GPU (RTX A1000 6GB). I read that the GPU is capable of using CUDA and cuDNN. Now I am trying to set up CUDA with cuDNN on WSL2 (Ubuntu 22.04) and Poetry. CUDA is recognized, but not cuDNN.
First of all I installed the CUDA driver like described in the following page: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaHVsZa2jTc
Then I tried to install the cuDNN driver from Nvidia's page (https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_local)
as a .deb and as a .tar, but still, after starting Python and importing TensorFlow, I get the following message:
E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
I searched the internet for several tutorials, but most of them are just related to Anaconda.
Does someone have a clean and clear instruction on how to set up WSL for using CUDA and cuDNN?

Make sure you have the correct compatibility software versions of the NVIDIA CUDA, the CUDA driver for your OS and the NVIDIA hardware. Based on the details provided, It seems like you are trying to install cuDNN 9.3.0 for CUDA 12.x. Therefore as per the specs you have provided(Ubuntu 22.04 & NVIDIA Ampere architecture) you should have,

CUDA Toolkit >= 12.0
NVIDIA Driver Version for Linux >=525.60.13

Refer to the CUDA toolkit installation guide here.
You can download NVIDIA divers here.
For full compatibility details, refer to the cuDNN Support Matrix.
Ubuntu users require Zlibg for cuDNN. You can install it by simply running sudo apt-get install zlib1g
Assuming you want to intsall cuDNN locally,

Run


wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cudnn/9.3.0/local_installers/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-9.3.0_1.0-1_amd64.deb


If your system architecture is ARM, replace the amd64.deb in the command with arm64.deb. Refer to the first of the three links provided in the bottom if your system architecture is different than the above two.

Navigate to your local directory containing the cuDNN Debian local installer file.

Enable the local repository.



sudo dpkg -i cudnn-local-repo-$distro-9.x.y_1.0-1_$architecture.deb


Import the CUDA GPG key.


sudo cp /var/cudnn-local-*/cudnn-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/


Refresh the repository metadata.


sudo apt-get update


Install the per-CUDA meta-packages


sudo apt-get -y install cudnn9-cuda-12


Verify the installation using following steps.


Run
sudo apt-get -y install libcudnn9-samples

Go to the writable path
cd $HOME/cudnn_samples_v9/mnistCUDNN

Compile the mnistCUDNN sample.
make clean && make

Run the mnistCUDNN sample.
./mnistCUDNN

If cuDNN is properly installed and running on your Linux system, you will see a message similar to the following:
Test passed!


For Detailed installations including installation for different system architectures, refer to the local installation guide here
If you want to do network installation, refer to the network installation guide here
For the whole documentation regarding the cuDNN installation on Linux, click here
I have faced similar issues when trying to install cuDNN in wsl for my system with RTX4060 GPU. Following these steps helped me solve the problem. If the issue persists, try doing a clean install. Remove the CUDA toolkit, NVIDIA driver and the cuDNN installation you have previously installed and reinstall them by following the steps in the installation guides provided.
Edit: Run the following code in whatever environment you are working and share the results
if gpus:
try:
    for gpu in gpus:
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
print(len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))


I have followed the instruction you've passed, but somehow cuDNN is still not working in tensorflow. I wasn't sure, if I installed CUDA correctly, but tensorflow is able to find CUDA, so I guess this worked.
For installing tensorflow I followed this instruction https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#wsl. In step https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#download-the-nvidia-cuda-toolkit I was asked after installation to install the missing nvidia driver with the flags --silent --driver and I did it. After this I followed your instr.

I also tried to install tensorflow and tensorflow[and-cuda] but both did not worked.


Are you 100% sure you have all the correct compatibility software versions?

2)What does your terminal returns when running nvidia-smi?
3)What kind of python environment are you working on? Conda or pip? Or does your system have both environments?

I have added the code snippet to my original answer. Run it and share the results. It's hard to add readable code in comments.


This helped me. I didn’t realize that nvidia don’t package cudnn with their wsl-ubuntu repo even though all their other repos include it. And tensorflow’s error message is terrible - I had to look at the strace to confirm that it was hunting around for cudnn and failing. Tensorflow should tell you what it’s failing to dlopen() at the very least.
